# How to properly implements Hibernate from an already existing database?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I'm trying to create a new Play application using JPA / Hibernate from an existing Mysql database.

`hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` in persistence file is set to "update".

My table posts has 6 entries.
Problem is when I execute an HQL statement like `"SELECT p FROM Posts p"`, I got an empty result, while if I execute a native query like `"SELECT * FROM posts"` I got my existing entries.

I think I'm missing something huge here, like hibernate's internal caching system or something, is there anything like this that can explain this empty result ? 
Does Hibernate has to build some specific cache when used from an existing database so that it returns correct results with HQL statements ? Why would it need such a thing ?

Comment: For an existing database, don't use auto-DDL. Make sure that you write entities that map cleanly onto your existing database schema; you probably have a mismatch with something like table names (e.g., normally the class name should be `Post`).

Comment: Thanks, you showed me the way, it was indeed a mapping problem with some field, it's weird that the app is able to run if hibernate doesn't pass his mapping check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My table posts has 6 entries. Problem is when I execute an HQL statement like "SELECT p FROM Posts p", I got an empty result, while if I execute a native query like "SELECT * FROM posts" I got my existing entries.

This sounds like you have to define mappings from mysql tables to jpa entities. You can generate them automatically using hibernate tools (like see an example [here](http://docs.jboss.org/tools/archive/2.0.0.GA/hibernatetools/en/html_single/index.html#plugins) on how to do that using an Eclipse plugin).

You should get some results from your query after that, Hibernate will populate its caches along the way.